# Is REST a good solution if you have lots of requests?

Tags: web-services, rest, jboss, arduino, web-controls

I want people to controll my arduino robot via the internet. It's important that the controlling reacts very fast. The user may send many requests per second.

Let me explain my **architecture**:

The user connects to a  **web-frontend**. He can use a virtual joystick and buttons. The frontend will then send orders (**like `"motor1:255" "motor2:0"....`**) to an **application server** (Wildfly).

When a frontend-session starts, **Wildfly** will establish a connection to my **computer or smartphone** using a **socket**. The orders will be passed to the arduino using **bluetooth**. When a frontend-session is not longer active, the socket will be closed.

One Wildfly should be able to controll up to 10 robots. One robot can be controlled by exactly one user. Some developers use a mysql table and add a row for each incoming order. I don't think this would work in my case.

**Is it okay to use REST** to send the orders from the frontend to the application server? Is there any other fast and secure way to transport the user input from the frontend to the business logic?

Goot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST, when properly understood and applied, is a solution for problems of long-term evolution and maintenance of your application. It doesn't seem to be your case.

What you mean is probably if an HTTP API is a good solution if you have lots of requests, and the answer is, it depends. I'd probably look into something like ZeroMQ for doing what you want.